# Ignore HealthMonitoring event by EventDetailCode

Tags: asp.net

I'm stumped on this one. We're using the HealthMonitoring API to log events in our app, including membership / forms authentication events (WebAuthenticationFailureAuditEvent).

The log is cluttered by lots of "The ticket supplied has expired" events, which has event code 4005.

I want to ignore these events, but I don't want to ignore all 4005 events, in case of someone attempting cookie tampering.

Does anyone know a way to ignore events based upon their EventDetailCode (in this case 50202).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event provider by inheriting from the System.Web.Management.WebEventProvider base provider class. This way you could handle the errors you want to by logging them and ignoring any others. Checkout "[How to Write a Custom Web Event Provider for ASP.NET 2.0](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/how_to_write_a_custom_web_event_provider_for_asp_net_2_0.aspx)" and "[Creating Custom Event Providers](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/sql/HealthMonitoring.aspx)" for more info.